# SP 2010 JavaScript Rich Text Editor Formatting

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, format, token

I have been running around in circles on this one.  I have a custom list item edit form in SharePoint 2010, and have everything working well except for one thing; the Rich Text fields.

I am currently making a web services call to another SP site, and am returning a value from a Rich Text column, and I need to, with JS/JQuery, set my local rich text field to the value returned.  When it comes back through the web service call, it is formatted with tokens, such as &lt instead of <, and &quot instead of ".

If I set the HTML value of the field on my form to equal this returned value, my field acutually displays what the HTML should be set to, but it doesn't acutally format.  It's like the text value is being set to the html value.

Here is what is happening:

**My code:**

```
//THIS SETS THE VALUE
myField.html(ReturnFieldValue('Description'));
```

*^ReturnFieldValue(field) is a function that just gets the text from the return string from GetListItems.*

**On source site (What I'm trying to return):**
  The quick **brown** fox jumps over the ***lazy*** dog.

**What I return with Web Service (GetListItems):**

> &ltdiv&gtThe quick &ltstrong&gt&ltfont
>   color=&quot#800000&quot&gtbrown&lt/font&gt&gt fox jumps over the
>   &ltem&gt&ltstrong&gtlazy&lt/strong&gt&lt/em&gt dog.&lt/div&gt

*^Each of those tags should have a ';' after them.*

**What I see after I set my local field's HTML to this returned value:**

```
  &lt;div&gt;The quick &lt;strong&gt;&lt;font
  color=&quot;#800000&quot;&gt;brown&lt;/font&gt;&gt; fox jumps over the
  &lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;lazy&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;
  dog.&lt;/div&gt;
```

***^^^ This right here is the trouble.  This is the ACTUAL TEXT that is DISPLAYING in the box, rather than the HTML being rendered.  I think it is because of the token formatting.***

Also, if I pass in the actual characters manually rather than the tokens, it works.  So how can I get the tokens to actually be the symbols?  Any help would be much appreciated...  Thank you!

Comment: html.replace(/&gt;/g,">").replace(/&lt;/g,"<") etc... MSIE's error page used to have a function that does all 4...

Comment: yes you need to change all the "&lt;" and "&gt;" to "<" and ">", then it should be recognized as a HTML code by jQuery